# Why the WSDL is including the web method name in its structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, wsdl, asmx

I have a web service.

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void SI_Equipment_Out_Async(DT_Equipment MT_Equipment)
    {
        //Internal working
    }
```

When I generate a wsdl out of it. It is like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SI_Equipment_Out_Async>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:MT_Equipment>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Equipment>
               <!--Optional:-->
```

The  is the name of the web method. Why does it include that? Becuase the wsdl client had given me for reference started from  . I used the same wsdl to create my web service but it includes the web method name too.

Why?

Comment: It's a method, so needs a name.  you haven't specified one so what else should it use?

Answer (score 1):

Done. Just put  [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)] over the [WebMethod] tag.

```
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [WebMethod]
    public void SI_Equipment_Out_Async(DT_Equipment MT_Equipment)
    {}
```